# add/merge items to pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to use pandas for storing some data in a structure like this:

```
Quantity Date Item Color  
15       0312 car    green  
10       0312 car    red  
3        0512 car    red
```

and be able to add an item to the structure:

```
3        0312 car  green
```

and get the structure updated as a result:

```
Quantity Date Item Color  
18       0312 car  green  
10       0312 car  red  
3        0512 car  red
```

Another example add:

```
-3        0512 car  red
```

Result:

```
Quantity Date Item Color  
18       0312 car  green  
10       0312 car  red
```

If the last 3 columns have the same values the quantity column is updates with a new value.
What is the closest data structure and function in pandas which support that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding DataFrames (`+`), pandas first aligns the indexes and the adds the values. So you aren't doing addition.

Instead you want use the index labels to select / drop.

First one:

```
df.loc[3] = [0312, 'car', 'green']  # or however you have that value stored.
```

Second one:

```
df = df.drop(3)
```

I'd encourage you to read the docs on [indexing and selecting data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.0/indexing.html)